# How can I group git changes in xcode by folder

Tags: xcode, git

I can't seem to find where I can group GIT changes by folder. Now I just see a flat list. Can anyone help me?

[image: current view]

Comment: If you want to see changed files in your project, you can go to the “Project Navigator” (the first tab) and then click on the “Show only files with source-control status” (the rightmost button down by the filter bar).

Comment: @Rob why not give that as an answer?

Comment: @matt I've posted it as an answer (although I admittedly am not entirely sure whether the OP was looking for, more narrowly, a tree-like view within the “Source Control navigator”)…

Comment: Maybe, but the fact is that although I use Xcode all day every day and frequently need to survey my uncommitted modifications, I didn't know of this feature.

Comment: I really wanted it to behave just like VSCode, you can simply show the changes list in the folder tree. Sad to see it's not there. : /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the “Source Control navigator”, you see a flat list:

[image]

But you can select the “Project navigator” and then click on the “Show only files with source-control status” button down on the filter bar to see your project structure with source files that have changed:

[image]

---

FWIW, you can also use third-party source control tools. For example, I like to use [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com), which gives me more control over which changes are staged for a commit, etc. Anyway, a lot of these tools also give you the ability to toggle between flat list and tree view:

[image]

Comment: My only regret is that I can't upvote this answer twice. What a great tip.

Comment: Thanks!
It's a bit harder to see the changes with this workaround, but I guess I'll stick to VSCode just for double checking before committing 